# Where and how i should use Redirect when i use Context

Tags: reactjs

I want to use Redirect when user logged in correctly.
In context file i have(only important things) :

```
  const [infoLog, setInfoLog] = React.useState("");
  const login = name => {
    setInfoLog(name);
  };
  <LoginInfo.Provider
      value={{
        login: login,
        logout: logout,
        infolog: infoLog
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </LoginInfo.Provider>
export const LoginInfoConsumer = LoginInfo.Consumer;
```

In login file i have(only impotant things) : 
Login method:

```
 const login = () => {
    if (tempLogin.login === "Login" && tempLogin.password == "Haslo") {
      setLogged(addTempLogin.login);
    }
```

return:

```
   <LoginPage>
        {logged != "" && (
          <div>
            <LoginInfoConsumer>
              <div>{({ login }) => <div>{login(logged)}</div>}</div>
            </LoginInfoConsumer>
          </div>
        )}
```

I don't know where i should insert Redirect , I tried in last part of code , but I can't do this correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I repaired my problem .
In LoginInfoConsumer outside `<div>` destroy all ways of `<Redirect>` 
I inserted `<Redirect>` in

```
const login = name => {
    setInfoLog(name);
    return <Redirect to="/page" />;
  };
```